How to add type definition on a single class which contains both static and instance properties/functions in TypeScript?
I was trying to follow this tutorial to try and answer my question initially, but it's not enforcing that I have implemented the static functions in my code. Here is what I have:
export type PackageForm<
  S extends PackageStaticForm = PackageStaticForm,
  I extends PackageInstanceForm = InstanceType<S>,
> = I

export type PackageStaticForm = {
  new (...args: Array<any>): any

  // link global package
  link: (take: PackageLinkFormInput) => void

  // save global package
  save: (take: PackageLinkFormInput) => void

  // verify global package
  test: (take: PackageLinkFormInput) => void

  // remove global package
  toss: (take: PackageLinkFormInput) => void
}

export type PackageInstanceForm = {
  // resolve file link
  find: (take: PackageFileFormInput) => void

  // link a package
  link: (take: PackageLinkFormInput) => void

  // install defined packages
  load: () => void

  // add a package
  save: (take: PackageLinkFormInput) => void

  // verify a deck
  test: (take: PackageLinkFormInput) => void

  // remove a package
  toss: (take: PackageLinkFormInput) => void
}

export default class Package implements PackageForm {
  #home: string

  #links: Record<string, Package>

  // save global package
  static save() {}

  // remove global package
  static toss({ link, mark, site }: PackageLinkFormInput) {}

  // verify global package
  static test({ link, mark, site }: PackageLinkFormInput) {}

  // link global package
  static link({ link, mark, site }: PackageLinkFormInput) {}

  constructor({ home }: PackageFormInput) {
    this.#home = home
    this.#links = {}
  }

  // install defined packages
  load() {}

  // add a package
  save({ link, mark, site }: PackageLinkFormInput) {}

  // remove a package
  toss({ link, mark, site }: PackageLinkFormInput) {}

  // verify a deck
  test({ link, mark, site }: PackageLinkFormInput) {}

  // link a package
  link({ link, mark }: PackageLinkFormInput) {}

  // resolve file link
  find({ file, base }: PackageFileFormInput) {}
}

export type PackageFileFormInput = {
  base?: string
  file: string
}

export type PackageFormInput = {
  home: string
}

export type PackageLinkFormInput = {
  link: string
  mark?: string
  site?: string
}

Is there any possible way to say that the class itself (the static parts) has a certain interface, in addition to specifying the implements XInterface on the instance, in TypeScript? If not, what is the closest one can come to solving this? If so, how do you do it?
A comment on that post suggests the following, but I don't see how it would get the IFConstructor type mapped to the class (and I'm running into the same problem, of it not enforcing that I have the static functions):
type IFConstructor = {
  new (): IF
  func1: () => void
}

type IF = {
  func2: () => void
}

class Obj implements IF {
  static func1() {}

  func2() {}
}


It's a missing feature of TS; see the linked q/a above. You can work around it by mentioning typeof Package again (or using the Package value somewhere that expects a PackageStaticform). If you slightly change your PackageForm as shown in this playground link you can get close to the behavior you want.
